# How to get GoodData PGP SSO Work?

Tags: single-sign-on, gooddata

I am trying to implement GoodData PGP key based Single Sign On based on the documentation but can't get it work. GoodData support confirmed that my keys are deployed on their servers, my user has my ssoProvider property set to what they provided, I think I am doing all what is expected but it just does not work.

Here is my initial JSON:
{ "email" : "myuser@example.com" , "validity": 1395089703026 }
I am signing it with my private key, encrypting with gooddatas public key, URLencoding and using as sessionId parameter of the URL but I still receive "UNABLE TO LOAD" error message.

Any ideas what can be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the time parameters (validity, notBefore, notOnOrAfter) need to be in unix timestamp format in seconds, not milliseconds.

Try this `{ "email" : "myuser@example.com" , "validity": 1395089703 }`

Answer (score 1):

everything looks OK.if your timestamp is not in pas and is not longer then now+36 hours. our recommendation s to set validity to now+12 - 24 hours.  If your problem still persist, please fill ticket on support.gooddata.com , because now we have to look at exact case.

please fill there username, sso provider and when did you try it last time.

Jiri Simon

GoodData support